# When $\cosh yx/2=\pm 1 $?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

When $\cosh \frac{xy}{2}=\pm 1 $?
is it correct to say $xy/2=cosh^{-1}(\pm1)$
Then $xy=2 \cosh^{-1}(\pm1)$

I think there is better solution for this problem? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum of $\cosh x$ occurs when $x=0$, so in this case you require $\frac{xy}{2}=0$ so you can conclude that either $x=0$ or $y=0$ or both

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I am assuming that the quantities in your equations are real numbers.

Since $\cosh u \ge 1$, with the minimum only occurring at $u = 0$, you're complicating the calculation too much.  You can conclude immediately that $xy = 0$, so either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ or both.  (EDITED, to correct silly error.)

---

By the way, since $\cosh$ is an even function, meaning that $\cosh(-u) = \cosh u$ for all $u \in \Bbb{R}$, it is **not** one-to-one, hence cannot have an inverse.  However, if you artificially restrict it's domain, say to $u \ge 0$ (so $\sinh u \ge 0$), then you can solve for the inverse:
$$
\cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u = 1 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\sinh^2 u = \cosh^2 u - 1
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \sinh u = \sqrt{\cosh^2 u - 1}
$$
Now,
\begin{align}
\cosh u + \sinh u &= e^u \\
\cosh u + \sqrt{\cosh^2 u - 1} &= e^u \\
\ln \bigl( \cosh u + \sqrt{\cosh^2 u - 1} \bigr) &= u \\
\end{align}
so if $x = \cosh u$ and $u \ge 0$, then
$$
u = \ln \bigl( x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \bigr),
$$
and this defines the restricted inverse.  [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k4zpwirf5w)'s a picture.

Comment: the minimum is at $ u = 0 $ not at $ u = 1$ please correct

Comment: Oops.  Thanks.  It was late.

Comment: no problem happens to me all the time (but i don't like wrong answer to remain on this website)